# Haskell: Why does RealFrac not imply Fractional?

Tags: haskell, types

NOTE: Full source code here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7085509

I have the following function:

```
tournament n p pop = do
    winner <- (\w -> min (n - 1) (floor (log w / log (1-p)))) <$> gaRandom
    (flip S.index) winner <$> S.sort <$> seqChoose n pop
```

Without a type signature, the compiler tells me the `tournament` signature is:

```
tournament
  :: (Floating a, Ord a1, RealFrac a, Random a) =>
     Int -> a -> S.Seq a1 -> StateT GA Data.Functor.Identity.Identity a1
```

Which looks fine with me. But when I use it:

```
t2 = do
    g <- newStdGen
    let a = evalState (tournament 5 0.9 (S.fromList [1..10])) (GA g)
    return ()
```

I get the error:

```
GA.hs:85:37:
    No instance for (Fractional a0) arising from the literal `0.9'
    The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
    Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Fractional Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
      instance Fractional Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
      instance Integral a => Fractional (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
        -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
      ...plus three others
    In the second argument of `tournament', namely `0.9'
    In the first argument of `evalState', namely
      `(tournament 5 0.9 (S.fromList [1 .. 10]))'
    In the expression:
      evalState (tournament 5 0.9 (S.fromList [1 .. 10])) (GA g)
```

**Which leads to my first question, why doesn't `RealFrac` imply `Fractional`? The type signature has RealFrac, but the error complains about lack of an instance for Fractional.**

Second, I copy-and-paste the type signature back into the code and add `Fractional a`:

```
tournament 
  :: (Floating a, Ord a1, RealFrac a, Fractional a, Random a) =>
     Int -> a -> S.Seq a1 -> State GA a1
tournament n p pop = do
    winner <- (\w -> min (n - 1) (floor (log w / log (1-p)))) <$> gaRandom
    (flip S.index) winner <$> S.sort <$> seqChoose n pop
```

And now the error I get is:

```
GA.hs:88:24:
    No instance for (Random a0) arising from a use of `tournament'
    The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
    Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Random Bool -- Defined in `System.Random'
      instance Random Foreign.C.Types.CChar -- Defined in `System.Random'
      instance Random Foreign.C.Types.CDouble
        -- Defined in `System.Random'
      ...plus 33 others
    In the first argument of `evalState', namely
      `(tournament 5 0.9 (S.fromList [1 .. 10]))'
    In the expression:
      evalState (tournament 5 0.9 (S.fromList [1 .. 10])) (GA g)
    In an equation for `a':
        a = evalState (tournament 5 0.9 (S.fromList [1 .. 10])) (GA g)
```

Which now confuses me further because I don't have a type variable `a0`. **Which leads to my second question: Obviously I'm misunderstanding something, but what?**

Comment: Erm, `RealFrac` does imply fractional (as in to be an instance of `RealFrac` requires `Fractional`)

Comment: FYI, I'm attempting to learn concepts from Genetic Algorithms and am choosing to reimplement many things. Pardon any obvious places where I could be using existing packages.

Comment: Can you make this example compilable? `seqChoose` and such are missing.

Comment: Sorry for the broken snippets. I've placed the full file on gist for review.

Answer (score 7):

In short, you need to fix a concrete type for `0.9` like `Double`. You can do that with an inline type annotation `(0.9 :: Double)`.

In long: numeric literals are a little strange in Haskell. In general, Haskell needs a way to project syntax (`0`, `0.0`, `0e0`) into semantics (`Int`, `Integer`, `Rational`, `Double`) while maintaining generality for as long as possible (`Num`, `Fractional`, `RealFrac`). Let's see how it's done.

If you type numeric literals by themselves you get generic types

```
>>> :t 1
1 :: Num a => a

>>> :t 1.0
1.0 :: Fractional a => a

>>> :t 1e0
1e0 :: Fractional a => a
```

Which means that we need to fix the concrete implementation of `a` before it can be used. In practice, this type variable `a` gets carried along

```
>>> :t [1,2,3]
[1,2,3] :: Num a => [a]
>>> :t [1e0,2,3]
[1e0,2,3] :: Fractional a => [a]
```

If it's helpful, it can be useful to think of the syntax as being translated like this

```
1     ===   fromInteger  (1   :: Integer)   :: Num a        => a
1.0   ===   fromRational (1.0 :: Rational)  :: Fractional a => a
```

But we can at various times eliminate the type variable

```
>>> :t show 3
show 3 :: String
```

How does Haskell know what the type of 3 is when we've never declared it? It defaults, when possible. In particular, if you turn on `-Wall` you'll see this

```
>>> show 1e3

<interactive>:63:6: Warning:
    Defaulting the following constraint(s) to type `Double'
      (Fractional a0)
        arising from the literal `1e3' at <interactive>:63:6-8
      (Show a0) arising from a use of `show' at <interactive>:63:1-4
    In the first argument of `show', namely `1e3'
    In the expression: show 1e3
    In an equation for `it': it = show 1e3

"1000.0"
```

This defaulting behavior [is controlled by an almost-never-used pragma `default`](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html) which "by default" is

```
default (Integer, Double)
```

Which works as

```
Each defaultable variable is replaced by the first type in the default list 
that is an instance of all the ambiguous variable's classes. It is a static 
error if no such type is found.
```

So, what's likely happening is that you're constraining `0.9` to some class which `Double` does not instantiate. During its search, Haskell is giving up after not finding the `Fractional` class and it introduces that new `a0` variable to represent this hitherto unreferenced, unknown type of `0.9`.

As stated at first, you probably want an inline annotation to `Double` to help the inferencer along. It's possible to add to your `default` list, but it's a bad idea as people rarely use that feature.

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't with the typeclasses, it's that GHC doesn't know which instance to use for `(Fractional a, RealFrac a, Floating a, Random a).  If you specify it as

```
tournament 5 (0.9 :: Double) (S.fromList [1..10])
```

Then it should work (or at least it worked for me using your gist)